# StreamingResponse FASTAPI returns strange file name

Tags: python-3.x, swagger, fastapi

I have an API that outputs `StreamingReponse` (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=fileresponse#streamingresponse) as zip/gz.
When I download the file VIA Swagger, I get a very strange name, for example:
`application_gz export something=1&something=1&something=Example&archive_type=gz blob https __<ip_address>_aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaaa`
so basically - with an ip address of the server, a uuid, some names. Is there anyway to change this to be something I decide, or atleast more elegant?
thanks!

Comment: `StreamingResponse(..., headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="yourfilename.zip"'}` should work, since `StreamingResponse` inherits from the general `Response` class.

Comment: @MatsLindh it doesn't work unfortunately: `content-disposition: attachment;filename = config.zip  content-type: application/zip  date: Thu,23 Jun 2022 10:41:27 GMT  server:xx ` these are the headers and i still get the weird file names.

Comment: whoops - fixed it- my problem was there was space between the `filename` and the `=`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header to give an alternative file name for the resource. Since `StreamingResponse` is a subclass of `Response`, you can set this by using the `headers` parameter:

```
return StreamingResponse(fp, headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="yourfilename.zip"'}
```

You can also use `inline` instead of `attachment` if you don't want to force a download but let the client display it directly instead (for example for PDF files).